# How to remove /sitecore/content/home from a URL using LinkManager?

Tags: link-manager

I have a scenario in which LinkManager returns the URL with /sitecore/content/home/myitem. Here my domain is www.abc.com and I want to access this item as www.abc.com/myitem instead of www.abc.com/sitecore/content/home/myitem.

This is how I am calling the item's URL using LinkManager:

```
@model FooterMenu
@{
    var myitem= @Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("{E29E4145-4754-4D45-B095-C490D93C9896}"));
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How is your site config? is the item below the same website? do you also want the https://www.abc.com in your url?,  LinkManager URLOptions alwaysIncludeServerUrl

Comment: @JanBluemink Yes, the URL should appear like this www.abc.com/myitem. There are other items also under the /sitecore/content node, that's why I can't set /sitecore/content/home node as rootpath in Site.config file.

Comment: You need the correct rootpath in your <sites><site name=...  and use: var options = LinkManager.GetDefaultUrlOptions();
options.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;
string link = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, options); or configer the LinkManager

Comment: Or create a custom LinkManager if you do not want to configer it properly, can  you clarify your question what exactly is your issue?, more specifiek.

Comment: @JanBluemink Right now, according to the code snippet "myitem" is returning path like this "www.abc.com/sitecore/content/home/myitem". I want it to be like this "www.abc.com/myitem". Because I am binding the "myitem" to a <div> in View.